# Align wrapping text correctly using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

This might be a totally silly question. Here is my problem -  I have a message box displayed in HTML (using `Bootstrap`) to show various user alerts. It has an information icon (using `bootstrap glyphicons`) and associated message. Everything looks fine unless the message is too long. Then the second line will wrap ***under*** the icon. I want the multiple lines to wrap starting where the first line starts.

**So this would be wrong:**

```
(i) This is an incorrect
format of the message
```

**And this would be right:**

```
(i) This is the correct
    format I want
```

My HTML/CSS is very simple:

```
<div class='alert alert-info'>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-information'></span>
&nbsp my message comes here.
</div>
```

But I looked at couple of sites including `css-tricks` and all the solutions seemed really complicated. So I am posting here to see if there is a quick and easy way to do this.

Comment: Why is there an `&nbsp;` ? That's creating extra space, and also remove any space between `</span>` and the beginning of your message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with CSS positioning, what you need to do is, push the entire element to the left using `margin-left: 30px;` and than, assign `position: relative;` to the container element so that we make sure that the `absolute` positioned element doesn't flow out in the wild.

Now we use `position: absolute;` for your glyph icon and use negative `left` value and a positive `top` value to set the icon correct, please tweak these values according to your requirements, rest stays the same

```
.alert {
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.alert .glyphicon {
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4feX/)

Comment: Thanks for that answer - let me try that out

Comment: I did not get to play with it too much due to other stuffs coming up. I will check it out soon - it definitely seems the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

what about wrapping your message inside it's own span and styling it to have a margin-left of 15px or whatever width the information icon is?  are you unable to do that?  if so, you can set the style on the

```
.alert .alert-info {
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

and subsequently set the margin on the span to 0

```
div .glyphicon glypicon-information{
    margin: 0;
}
```